# What are the benefits of limiting FPS OpenGl

Tags: java, opengl, game-loop

Recently I have been working on a small game, I have been using this method `Display.sync(FPS_CAP);` which limits the fps to whatever you want. My game runs on a tick based system so game logic (like player speed) will not be affected by fps dips, however, everywhere online says you should limit your FPS to something about 60 - 120. Is there a point to doing this? I know most screens can only refresh around 60 times per second (mine is 60 Hz), I just don't see the point in limiting FPS to what the screen can render?

Comment: Ignoring the refresh rate can cause [screen tearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing) and [judder](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/judder).

Comment: [Game Development.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits of limiting FPS are three-fold (at least).

1. Unlimited FPS can cause ugly visual artifacts. The number of frames rendered between each refresh will not be the same each time.
2. It's wasteful. Why are you rendering and swapping buffers when it won't even be displayed on screen?
3. If you happen to include anything like game logic in your render loop (which you may wish to avoid anyway), your output will end (even more) up chopped up and jittery.